# Can't check any option of h:selectOneRadio inside h:extendedDatatable JSF

Tags: jsf, radio-button, richfaces

I'm facing a problem related to `radioButtons` inside a `rich:column` of a `h:extendedDatatable`.

I've been reading several blogs and some questions right here in stackoverflow but almost everyone seems to want to put the radioButton options spread through several rows. This is not my case: **I'd need to show 'n' groups of three radios every row in my table.**

I can't find what I'm doing wrong because I tried putting the radioGroup out of the table and everything worked fine. However, if I put them into the `rich:column` all my radios appear unchecked.

Here the current code for the column:

```
<rich:column id="CCATEG_column" >
    <h:selectOneRadio id="CCATEG" value="2">
        <f:selectItem id="CCATEG_MANAGER" itemValue="1" itemLabel="" />
        <f:selectItem id="CCATEG_COMANAGER" itemValue="2" itemLabel="" />
        <f:selectItem id="CCATEG_MEMBER" itemValue="3" itemLabel="" />
    </h:selectOneRadio>
</rich:column>
```

I've tried with `h:selectOneRadio` and wih `t:selectOneRadio` (tomahawk). Both of them show me the three radios unchecked every row, even when I'm specifying `value="2"` Any help?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/h/selectOneRadio.html) the @value is supposed to be a ValueExpression, so a hard-coded value will not do (I assume this isn't the final use-case). This will work:

```
<rich:dataTable value="#{bean.intList}" var="value">
    <rich:column>
        <h:selectOneRadio value="#{value}">
            <f:selectItem itemValue="1" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="2" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="3" />
        </h:selectOneRadio>
    </rich:column>
</rich:dataTable>
```

By the way, your example doesn't work with standard `<h:dataTable>`, `<h:column>` either.

Comment: Sorry for my delay. I was trying to resolve this and other issues... You are right, it's not the final use-case. Even though, I had the code like yours but it didn't work for me... This should be a deeper issue... JSF magic (for me). Anyway, thank you so much, @Makhiel

Comment: Finally, it was an internal error from my web service... It was very important being sure of my client solution because of your answer. Thank you so much.